# 2 consecutive for loops will not run

Tags: batch-file

Why is batch not running this second for loop? What am i doing wrong? The first loop runs fine, but the second loop is never hit. I even put an echo statement after the first loop and it is not even displayed.

```
FOR /D %%X in (..\Apps\Mine\*) do if exist "%%X\AndroidManifest.xml" ("%1\android.bat" update project -p "%%X") else (
echo This is not an android project.
)

FOR /D %%Y in (..\Apps\Theirs\*) do if exist "%%Y\AndroidManifest.xml" ("%1\android.bat" update project -p "%%Y") else (
echo This is not an android project.
)
```

---

**More details**

*The current working directory also has no `()` or spaces in the name.*

*Windows7 64bit.*

*This is the exact argument i am using:*

```
> update_project.bat C:\Users\MyUserName\android-sdks\tools
```

*That is all the contents of the batch script. There is nothing else in it.*

*Here is the directory structure. The batch script is run from the CWD.*

- Projects

  - Apps

    - Mine

      - App1
      - App2
    - Theirs

      - App3
      - App4
  - Tools (CWD)

Comment: does `Theirs` have subdirectories?

Comment: yes. Just like `Mine`. I will add examples to the details.

Comment: could possibly `%1` contain a parenthese? Like `program files(x86)`?

Comment: No, I will add the exact argument to more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `CALL` statement in front of `"%1\android.bat"`. If you don't use `CALL`, control will not be returned from `"%1\android.bat"`.

Like this,

```
FOR /D %%X in (..\Apps\Mine\*) do if exist "%%X\AndroidManifest.xml" (CALL "%1\android.bat" update project -p "%%X") else (
echo This is not an android project.
)

FOR /D %%Y in (..\Apps\Theirs\*) do if exist "%%Y\AndroidManifest.xml" (CALL "%1\android.bat" update project -p "%%Y") else (
echo This is not an android project.
)
```

Comment: That worked, however, i had to do it like this `(CALL "%1\android.bat" update project -p "%%X")`. Where the `CALL` is outside the quotes. Thanks

Comment: @prolink007 Oops...yes the `CALL` should be outside the quotes. I fixed my answer.

Comment: lol, we all "Oops" on occassions. Some more than others. **points at self**